# filter the data using different columns and pick latest using hive or sql

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

We have a requirement where we need to get the latest record for field f1 based on timestamp.

1. within same f1 field we need to fetch latest record.
2. incase field f2 has value 3 within same field value f1 then we need to check field f4 of that record matches with value in field f3 for rest of the records within field f1
   and we need to eliminate then whatever remains we need to take latest record from that.

input:

---

| f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | key1b | keyc | 1:00:00 |
| a1 | 1 | abc | key1c | 1:20:00 |
| a1 | 3 | key1 | abc | 1:30:00 |
| b1 | 1 | key1b | keyc | 1:00:00 |
| b1 | 1 | key1a | key1 | 1:20:00 |
| b1 | 1 | key1 | abc | 1:30:00 |
| c1 | 1 | abc1 | key2 | 1:00:00 |
| c1 | 1 | abc2 | key1 | 1:20:00 |
| c1 | 3 | key1 | abc1 | 1:30:00 |
| c1 | 3 | key2 | abc2 | 1:30:00 |
| c1 | 4 | key3 | abc2 | 1:30:00 |
| c1 | 2 | key3 | abc2 | 1:35:00 |

output:

---

| f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | key1b | keyc | 1:00:00 |
| b1 | 1 | key1 | abc | 1:30:00 |
| c1 | 2 | key3 | abc2 | 1:35:00 |

Comment: window function might be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Input can be filtered according to condition 2) with "left_anti" join, and then latest record selected with window function (Spark+Scala):

```
val input = Seq(
  ("a1", 1, "key1b", "keyc", "1:00:00"),
  ("a1", 1, "abc", "key1c", "1:20:00"),
  ("a1", 3, "key1", "abc", "1:30:00"),
  ("b1", 1, "key1b", "keyc", "1:00:00"),
  ("b1", 1, "key1a", "key1", "1:20:00"),
  ("b1", 1, "key1", "abc", "1:30:00"),
  ("c1", 1, "abc1", "key2", "1:00:00"),
  ("c1", 1, "abc2", "key1", "1:20:00"),
  ("c1", 3, "key1", "abc1", "1:30:00"),
  ("c1", 3, "key2", "abc2", "1:30:00"),
  ("c1", 4, "key3", "abc2", "1:30:00"),
  ("c1", 2, "key3", "abc2", "1:35:00")
).toDF("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "timestamp")

val invalidF4 = input.where($"f2" === 3).select("f1", "f4")

val filtered = input
  .filter($"f2" =!= 3)
  .alias("main")
  .join(
    invalidF4.alias("invalid"),
    $"main.f1" === $"invalid.f1" && $"main.f3" === $"invalid.f4",
    "left_anti")

val f1TimestampWindow = Window.partitionBy("f1").orderBy(desc("timestamp"))
val result = filtered
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(f1TimestampWindow))
  .where($"row_number" === 1)
  .drop("row_number")
```

Result:

```
+---+---+-----+----+---------+
|f1 |f2 |f3   |f4  |timestamp|
+---+---+-----+----+---------+
|b1 |1  |key1 |abc |1:30:00  |
|a1 |1  |key1b|keyc|1:00:00  |
|c1 |2  |key3 |abc2|1:35:00  |
+---+---+-----+----+---------+
```